# How To Create Data Become Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How do we write a SQL query for this situation?
The structure of the table is;

```
| Room | BLOK | DATA |
|   1  |   A  |  12  |
|   2  |   A  |  13  |
|   1  |   B  |  14  |
|   3  |   B  |  15  |
```

Expected Output:

```
| Room |   A  |  B   |
|   1  |   12 |  14  |
|   2  |   13 | null |
|   3  |  null|  15  |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using conditional aggregation

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=508eb7044c463d6f7fe7c03abf1cd9e8)**

```
select room, max(case when BLOK='A' then DATA end) as A,
max(case when BLOK='B' then DATA end) as B
from tablename
group by room
```

OR Try using `PIVOT`

```
select room,pv.* from 
tablename
pivot(max(DATA) for BLOK in ([A],[B])) pv
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Room    A   B
1      12   14
2      13   
3           15
```

For Dynamic Pivot

```
declare @sql varchar(max)='',@col_list varchar(8000)=''

set @col_list = (select distinct quotename([BLOK])+',' from tablename
for xml path(''))

set @col_list = left (@col_list,len(@col_list)-1)

set @sql = 'select Room,'+@col_list+' from
tablename
pivot (max([DATA]) for [BLOK] in ('+@col_list+'))pv'

exec(@sql)
```

**[FIDDLE FOR DYNAMIC PIVOT](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1837d32a98618fbd67d9dadf6450ac33)**

Comment: How I edit "in value" as dynamic value from table.
I have same error with above comment


select ROOM, COUNT(*) AS DATA,BLOK from 
DOR_PERSON WHERE BLOK IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY BLOK,ROOM 
pivot(max(DATA) for BLOK in (SELECT DISTINCT BLOK FROM DOR_PERSON WHERE BLOK IS NOT NULL)) pv

Comment: yups @fa06 dunamic BLOK and ROOM , I ahve try your code its work if value BLOK is hard code, but when I try to make it dynamic is error

with t1 as
(
select 1 as Room, '1' as BLOK, 1 as DATA
union all
select 12,'12',1
union all
select 2,'2',1
union all
select 1,'Test',1

)
select pv.* from 
t1
pivot(max(DATA) for BLOK in (SELECT 
 STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(BLOK) 
                    from t1
                    group by BLOK
                    order by BLOK
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')AS BLOK)) pv

Comment: @WelldyRosman, I've edited my answer for dynamic pivot - you can check

Comment: can you explain what set,declare,exec function?? I so sorry my knownledge about sql is too poor, when i copy your code to sql editor its not work, but i know that its the right answer , because on many article explain such this

Comment: for dynamic query you need to build the query and for this you've to declare variable, set is for define value in variable and exec is for executing the defined sql @WelldyRosman

Comment: Msg 156 Level 15 State 1 Line 12
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'declare'.

Comment: @WelldyRosman, have you checked my fiddle - it works fine there

Comment: @WelldyRosman you can check here - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1837d32a98618fbd67d9dadf6450ac33

Answer (score 1):

You may try [PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017)

Try below query with your table and data to get the required result.

**Query:**

```
select [Room],
        [A] as A,
        [B] as B
from
--Step2 get the actual data
(
select Room,
        Block,
        Data
        From SOPivot
) as PivotData

--step3 pivot function
pivot
(
sum(Data) for Block in 
(A,B))as Pivoting
order by Room
```

Comment: Its Not work, 

select [ROOM]
       ,SELECT DISTINCT ROOM FROM DOR_PERSON WHERE ROOM IS NOT NULL
from
 (
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS DATA,BLOK,ROOM  FROM DOR_PERSON 
  WHERE BLOK IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY MESCODE,BLOK,ROOM 
 ) as PivotData
pivot
(
 sum(DATA) for BLOK in 
(SELECT DISTINCT BLOK FROM DOR_PERSON WHERE BLOK IS NOT NULL))as Pivoting
order by ROOM

Comment: Hey @WelldyRosman You need to check your query, please read about how to use pivot before directly applying into your table and queries.

Comment: I dont know what mush I do :-(

select T1.ROOM,pv.* from (
SELECT COUNT(*) AS DATA,BLOK,ROOM  FROM DOR_PERSON 
  WHERE BLOK IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY MESCODE,BLOK,ROOM) AS T1 
pivot(max(DATA) for BLOK in (STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(BLOK) 
                    from DOR_PERSON
                    group by BLOK
                    
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,''))) pv